# Is it possible to run F# WebApi (OWIN) project in Azure Web Roles?

Tags: c#, azure, f#, azure-web-roles

I'm not sure if this is F# specific or something else, but what could cause the following error message when trying to debug locally an Azure cloud service:

> The Web Role in question doesn't seem to be a web application type project.

I added an *empty* F# web api Project to a solution (which adds Global.asax etc., I added an OWIN startup class Startup etc.) and then from an existing cloud service project I picked `Roles` and chose `Add -> Web Role Project in solution`, which finds the F# web project (its project type guids are `349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21` and `F2A71F9B-5D33-465A-A702-920D77279786`), of which the first one seem to be exactly the GUID that defines a web application type.

However, when I try to start the cloud project locally, I get the aforementioned error message. I have a C# Web Role project that will start when I remove the F# project. I also have F# *worker role* projects that start with the C# web role project if I remove this F# *web role* project. If I set the F# web project as a startup project, it starts and runs as one would expect, normally.

Now, it makes me wonder if this is something with F# or could this error message appears inC# too, but I didn't find anything on Google. Can anyone shed light into this?

**<edit:** Additionally, in the F# trying to open `Package/Publish Web` tab in project settings will give the following error message

> An error occurred trying to load the page. Specified cast is not valid.

I suspect this doesn't matter and may be just a bug in how VS handles the project or in [F# MVC 5 template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39ae8dec-d11a-4ac9-974e-be0fdadec71b).

**<edit for a solution of sort:**

It looks like a solution to create e Web Role as a C# project and then include the web projects as ordinary F# projects works. A caveat here is that during this time the F# Web API template was updated. As of now, I used Web API 2.2 and Katana 3.0 from the 1.13 version of F# MVC template. As a bonus amongst many things, it looks this model has the added benefit of reduced deployment package size as blogged by **Olaf Loogman** at [Reducing the size of an Azure Web Role deployment package](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/10/28/reducing-the-size-of-an-azure-web-role-deployment-package/).

Rather straightforward instructions for publishing multiple sites for one role can be had from [Tips for Publishing Multiple Sites in a Web Role](https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specified cast not valid error happens with older versions of F# tooling. 3.1.2 should fix that issue.

I personally have created standard worker roles projects without a problem, and f# websites hosted in azure, but not f# web roles - I suspect that the support for them isn't great. Out of curiosity, why are you using a web role rather than a website project?

Comment: I thought to install a [HSTS module](http://hstsiis.codeplex.com/) to IIS and in some way that's the easy way out to without trying to poach for documentation what's there for Web Sites and just disable a lot of stuff IIS has and make my own configurations (installing HSTS isn't possible to Web Sites, I believe), I mean something like [this](http://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12). Going with compute roles and the self-hosted route forgoes some IIS benefits still, e.g. with regard to scalability and perhaps certs etc.

Comment: Websites also gives you some other things that Cloud Services don't - for example, there's a free hosting option for websites, they deploy much quicker that a web role and you can make app.settings and connection strings configuration changes to websites directly in the Azure portal. In general, if you just want an IIS-hosted website they are a better fit IMHO.

Comment: I haven't tried web roles either. I'll try later and report back.

Comment: Indeed, I have been testing with various options lately. One biggish issue, besides on how would I go about HSTS, Perfect Forward Secrecy etc. is that I'd do it [cheaply](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/07/scaling-standard-azure-website-to-380k.html). Now, it looks like, Web Sites also support [virtual networks](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/) and if this really is so, it looks like I can connect them to compute roles and ultimately to on-premises resources (if this were a part of a bigger deployment) and then it's about security features...